# How to suppress scroll-into-view behavior in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, focus, flutter-appbar, flutter-scaffold

I have a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar` that hides on scroll.

On the app bar is a search button that, when pressed, puts a `TextField` into the app bar.

When the field gets focus, it causes the scroll view to scroll all the way to the top, and the app bar gets stuck up in the "unsafe" area:

[image: scroll on focus issue]

The [Scaffold docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html#scaffold-layout-the-keyboard-and-display-notches) mention that when the keyboard is shown the scaffold's insets change and the scaffold is rebuilt, causing the "focused widget will be scrolled into view if it's within a scrollable container".

This seems like the behavior I don't want. I looked but couldn't understand the mechanism or how to suppress it. Is doing so possible?

The source code for the view in the image is [here](https://github.com/amake/orgro/blob/19c1122bfaea861e8151221632e4ee994c1a1747/lib/src/pages/document.dart#L158).

Also I note that this problem didn't happen in my previous implementation with non-sliver, standard widgets. I suspect this is because the app bar was not in a scrollable view, whereas `SliverAppBar` is inside the `CustomScrollView` so that it can interact with the main body.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem but try to make
App bar with `floating: true, pinned: true, snap: true` . [Doc Reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

Comment: I don’t want it pinned, so even if that addressed the scrolling and/or safe area issues, it still wouldn’t solve my problem.

Comment: ok. just asking, setting `pinned: false,` again gives scrolling/SafeArea issue?

Comment: The gif above shows the `pinned: false` case. The `pinned: true` case keeps the app bar locked in the right place, but the content underneath still scrolls, and it scrolls to a slightly wrong offset (overlapped a bit by bar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: This issue was fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/56413) which appears to have first landed in Flutter 1.22.0.**

It took some sleuthing, but I eventually found the mechanism for this behavior.

`TextField` wraps `EditableText`. When the latter gains focus, it will invoke [`_showCaretOnScreen`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2962912d68fb72d6c9fd60f652e27f3593d692d6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart#L1858), which includes [a call to `renderEditable.showOnScreen`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2962912d68fb72d6c9fd60f652e27f3593d692d6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart#L1904). This bubbles up and eventually causes the scrolling behavior.

We can force `_showCaretOnScreen` to return early [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2962912d68fb72d6c9fd60f652e27f3593d692d6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart#L1865) if we supply to the `TextField` a hacked `ScrollController` that always returns `false` from `hasClients`:

```dart
class _HackScrollController extends ScrollController {
  // Causes early return from EditableText._showCaretOnScreen, preventing focus
  // gain from making the CustomScrollView jump to the top.
  @override
  bool get hasClients => false;
}
```

The behavior does not seem intentional, so I reported it as [bug #60422](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60422).

## Caveats

This workaround may not be very stable.

I don't know what adverse effects the `hasClients` override might have.

The [docs for `TextField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/scrollController.html) say that the `scrollController` is used "when vertically scrolling the input". In this use case we don't want vertical scrolling anyway, so the workaround might not cause any problems. In my brief testing it didn't seem to cause problems with horizontal (overflow) scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the documentation mentions try and use resizeToAvoidBottomInset parameter to false (defaults to true) in the scaffold widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html

Also I would recommend creating ValueListenableBuilder after the scaffold (as the first widget in the body) to avoid rebuilding the whole scaffold and just the body widget

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` doesn't affect this. The `ValueListenableBuilder` is outside the scaffold because in the previous implementation I needed to use the result value when building the scaffold. But yes, it could be moved inside now.

Comment: What about using resizeToAvoidBottomInset and wrapping the widget with a SafeArea?

Comment: `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` has no effect on this at all. `SafeArea` around the app bar a) makes it look weird, since the app bar *should* be in the unsafe area a little bit, and b) and doesn't affect the scroll-to-top behavior.

Comment: are you using SliverSafeArea for the SliverAppBar? or just SafeArea over the Scaffold?

Comment: It doesn't matter because both are wrong: both the scaffold and the app bar *need* to be in the unsafe area. And that still doesn't address the scrolling behavior.